# Unit test pg emitter in Promise got

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I am creating an Unit test of Javascript. Here is my code.
I have 2 functions in quizHandler_getfull.js. 
1. rreject : It will handle the error in the same format.
2. getquizid : It does query and then emits the signal.

Next file is an unit test file. I use mocha framework with proxyquire.
I had created client object and then put into the target function.
Howerver, I got the error mentions on reference.

I suspect client.query() is never been called by unit tester.
Where am I missing here?

**quizHandler_getfull.js** :

```
exports.rreject = function(error,pid){
    //pid = product id
    var data = { success : false,
                 id : pid ,
                 reason : { errmsg : error.detail,
                            errid : error.code}};
    console.log('error');
    return data;
};

exports.getquizid = function(client,pid){
    return new Promise(function(fulfill,reject){
    var qstr = "SELECT quiz_id, to_char(maxtime, 'HH24:MI:SS') as maxtime, subject_id, author_id, description, difficulty, name, product_id, to_char(lastmodified at time zone 'utc', 'YYYY-MM-DD\
\"T\"HH24:MI:SSZ') as lastmodified FROM dugong.quiz WHERE product_id = $1";
    var qzid = client.query(qstr,[pid]);
    qzid.on('error',function(err){
        console.log('error');
        console.log('getquizid function');
        console.log(err);
        var data = exports.rreject(err,pid);
        reject(data);
    });
    qzid.on('row',function(row){
        fulfill(row);
    });
    qzid.on('end',function(row){
        if(row.rowCount == 0 ){
        var err = { detail : 'ID not found',
                code : 'Quiz_101'};
        reject(err);
        }
    });
    });    
};
```

**quizHandler_getfull.test.js** :

```
var httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');
var test = require('unit.js');
var assert = require('assert');
var real_quizHandler = require('../../routes/quizHandler_getfull.js');

var proxyquire =  require('proxyquire')
, pgStub   =  { };
var quizHandler_getfull, response, request
describe('quizHandler_getfull : ', function () {

    beforeEach(function(){
    request  = httpMocks.createRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/quizzes/full',
        params : {id : 1}
    });
    pgStub.end = function(){}; 
    quizHandler_getfull = proxyquire('../../routes/quizHandler_getfull.js', { 'pg' : pgStub} );
    response = httpMocks.createResponse();
    });
    it('getquizid should show query error. If database rejects query.', function (done) {
    var client = {};
    client.query = function(querystr, pid){
        var emitter = new events.EventEmitter();
        setTimeout(function(){
        emitter.emit('error', {detail: 'This is fake query error', code : 'error666'})
        },0);
        console.log('hi there');
        return emitter;
    };

    //Memo : put anonymous done() to avoid conflict with mocha's done.
    Promise.all([quizHandler_getfull.getquizid(client,1)]).then(
        //function fulfill(output){},
        null,
        function reject(er){
        console.log('before done');
        console.log(er);
        console.log('done here');
        done();
        }
    );
    });
});
```

**My error** :

```
before done
[ReferenceError: events is not defined]
done here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you doesn't import ***events***. 
According to node.js documentation it must be something like:

```
 var EventEmitter = require('events');
```

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html